# Reading hive orc table using spark

Tags: apache-spark, hive

I have a partitioned table. Partitons from `2017-06-20` and up.

[image]

My query.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.hive.orc._
import org.apache.spark.sql._
val hiveContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc)
val test_enc_orc = hiveContext.sql("select * from db.tbl where time_key = '2017-06-21' limit 1")
```

Every time I run it, spark looks for this partition `2017-06-20`

```
INFO OrcFileOperator: ORC file hdfs://nameservice1/apps/hive/warehouse/db.db/tbl/time_key=2017-06-20/000016_0 has empty schema, it probably contains no rows. Trying to read another ORC file to figure out the schema.
```

and searches for all files for date `2017-06-20`. It holds empty ORC files. But partition `2017-06-21` has files with data. Why doesn't spark search that date or any other?

EDIT

Created test table

```
drop table arstel.evkuzmin_test_it;

create table arstel.evkuzmin_test_it(name string)
partitioned by(ban int)
stored as orc;

insert into arstel.evkuzmin_test_it partition(ban) values
("bob", 1)
, ("marty", 1)
, ("monty", 2)
, ("naruto", 2)
, ("death", 4);
```

Seems like the problem is exactly because of empty files. In this case there are none, so everything works. Is there a way to make spark ignore them?

Comment: Could you please check table partition mapping? whether partition 2017-06-21 is match to correct path i.e. hdfs://nameservice1/apps/hive/warehouse/fair_usage.db/agg_fair_usage_plan_charge_d/time_key=2017-06-21/

Comment: @Manish Added an image. plus, `hadoop fs -ls /apps/hive/warehouse/fair_usage.db/agg_fair_usage_plan_charge_d` shows the same result. the paths are correct.